# How to extract domain name without www from url

Tags: swift

What would be the easiest way to get just domain name from the URL.

Input:

```
http:// www.domain.com
http:// domain.com
https:// www.domain.com
https:// domain.com
```

P.S. I've added space after // as it doesn't allow me save otherwise.

Output:

```
domain.com
```

Following is my attempt, is there any better way than this?

```
if let urlString = profile.url {
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let host = url?.host
    if let array = host?.split(separator: ".") {
        let arraySlice = array.suffix(2)
        let domain = arraySlice[1] + "." + arraySlice[2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove an optional `www.` with `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:)`

```
if let urlString = profile.url,
    let url = URL(string: urlString),
    let host = url.host {
    let domain = host.replacingOccurrences(of: "^www.", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    print(domain)  // "example.com\n"
}
```

Comment: Space was deliberately added editor doesn't allow me to save it.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that